# Can the public tell if Apache2 serves multiple vhosts from the same directory?

Tags: apache-2.2

Is the public able to tell (read: *googlebot*) that my Apache2 server is serving multiple `VirtualHosts` from the same directory? Or is that fact not revealed to the public?

Disregard the fact that the same files are being served. They are dynamic PHP files, in my case.

My guess is that this info is not revealed to the public, but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the public is not going to know.

Apache2 does not show the path to your DocumentRoot, but a simple php script (phpinfo) can extract that data from the server variables.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't tell the difference between identical content in different locations and content served from the same location, unless you're leaking debug information (PHP errors being dumped into the HTML stream is the most common one I can think of).